# How can I toy with this .py file?

Tags: python

I'm learning Python just so I can tinker with the [files from AIMA](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/code.html) easily. I know Java and C++, but I find the AIMA code on the repositories to be too obfuscated. The Python code looks simpler and more elegant...yet, I don't know Python.

I wanna import the functions in [search.py](http://aima-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/search.py).

I tried creating a search2.py file like this:

```
import search

class Problem2(Problem):
    pass
```

on the folder where search.py is and got:

```
~/aima/aima-python$ python search2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search2.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Problem2(Problem):
NameError: name 'Problem' is not defined
```

Why is this?

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188929/why-import-when-you-need-to-use-the-full-name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you `import search`, you define the name `search`, as a module created from executing search.py.  If in there is a class called `Problem`, you access it as `search.Problem`:

```
import search

class Problem2(search.Problem):
    pass
```

An alternative is to define `Problem` with this statement:

```
from search import Problem
```

which executes search.py, then defines `Problem` in your file as the name `Problem` from the newly-created search module.  Note that in this form, the name `search` is not defined in your file.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options here:

1. Instead of `import search`, write `from search import Problem`
2. Instead of `class Problem2(Problem)`, write `class Problem2(search.Problem)`

Answer (score 0):

If class `Problem` is located in the `search` module, you have to import it either like that `from search import Problem` or use it like that:

```
import search

class Problem2(search.Problem):
    pass
```