# How does importing a function from a module work in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

I have a module `some_module.py` which contains the following code:

```
def testf():
    print(os.listdir())
```

Now, in a file named `test.py`, I have this code:

```
import os
from some_module import testf

testf()
```

But executing test.py gives me `NameError: name 'os' is not defined`. I've already imported `os` in `test.py`, and `testf` is in the namespace of `test.py`. So why does this error occur?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`import` is not the same as including the content of the file as if you had typed it directly in place of the `import` statement. You might think it works this way if you're coming from a C background, where the `#include` preprocessor directive does this, but Python is different.

The `import` statement in Python reads the content of the file being imported and evaluates it in its own separate context - so, in your example, the code in `some_module.py` has no access to or knowledge of anything that exists in `test.py` or any other file. It starts with a "blank slate", so to speak. If `some_module.py`'s code wants to access the `os` module, you have to import it at the top of `some_module.py`.

When a module is imported in Python, it becomes an *object*. That is, when you write

```
import some_module
```

one of the first things Python does is to create a new object of type `module` to represent the module being imported. As the interpreter goes through the code in `some_module.py`, it assigns any variables, functions, classes, etc. that are defined in that file to be attributes of this new module object. So in your example, the module object will have one attribute, `testf`. When the code in the function `testf` wants to access the variable `os`, it looks in the function itself (local scope) and sees that `os` is not defined there, so it then looks at the attributes of the module object which `testf` belongs to (this is the "global" scope, although it's not truly global). In your example, it will not see `os` there, so you get an error. If you add

```
import os
```

to `some_module.py`, then that will create an attribute of the module under the name `os`, and your code will find what it needs to.

You may also be interested in some other answers I've written that may help you understand Python's `import` statement:

- [Why import when you need to use the full name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188929/why-import-when-you-need-to-use-the-full-name/3189105#3189105)
- [Does Python import statement also import dependencies automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367255/does-python-import-statement-also-import-dependencies-automatically/29367398#29367398)

Answer (score 2):

The *name* `testf` is in the namespace of `test`.  The *contents* of the `testf` function are still in `some_module`, and don't have access to anything in `test`.

If you have code that needs a module, you need to import that module in the same file where that code is.  Importing a module only imports it into the one file where you import it.  (Multiple imports of the same module, in different files, won't incur a meaningful performance penalty; the actual loading of the module only happens once, and later imports of the same module just get a reference to the already-imported module.)

Answer (score 2):

Importing a module adds its name as an attribute of the *current* scope. Since different modules have independent scopes, any code in `some_module` cannot use names in `__main__` (the executed script) without having imported it first.